# How can I return specializable associated type from default method?

Tags: rust, specialization

I'm [implementing tuple flattening](https://github.com/kdy1/rust-toys/tree/master/flatten) for Rust. It requires converting

```
((A,B), (C, (D, E)), F)
```

into

```
Cons[
    Cons[A, B, Nil],
    Cons[
        C, Cons[D, E, Nil], Nil
    ],
    F,
    Nil
]
```

I tried using specialization, but the compiler doesn't like it:

```
/// For non-tuple types.
impl<T> IntoCons for Val<T> {
    default type Out = Cons<T, Nil>;

    default fn into_cons(self) -> Cons<T, Nil> {
        Cons {
            head: self,
            tail: Nil,
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this? Any alternative that doesn't use `unsafe` is ok.

Complete example:

```
#![feature(specialization)]
use std::fmt::{Debug, Display};

pub trait Tr {
    type It;
    fn it(self) -> Self::It;
}

impl<T> Tr for T
where
    T: Debug,
{
    default type It = u8;

    default fn it(self) -> Self::It {
        0
    }
}

impl<T> Tr for T
where
    T: Debug + Display,
{
    type It = u16;

    fn it(self) -> Self::It {
        0
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fb6be449ccd86605b3e5c5d5a0831d68&version=nightly)

Compiler output:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:17:9
   |
16 |     default fn it(self) -> Self::It {
   |                            -------- expected `<T as Tr>::It` because of return type
17 |         0
   |         ^ expected associated type, found integral variable
   |
   = note: expected type `<T as Tr>::It`
              found type `{integer}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are returning `Self::It` but give it a 0. What happens if someone were to implement this with `It` being `String`? Since there is no way to prove that this is always going to be a number, you either need a trait bound or to change the method signature.

A possible way of doing it is like this:

```
pub trait Tr {
    type It: Default;
    fn it(self) -> Self::It;
}

impl<T> Tr for T
where
    T: Debug,
{
    default type It = u8;

    default fn it(self) -> Self::It {
        Default::default()
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bd3d0dedf37da56792ed636f28f66558&version=undefined)

Comment: *What happens if someone were to implement this with It being `String`* — this isn't the implementation in the *trait*, it's a blanket implementation. If you [remove the `default` and the specialized impl](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=bbeb840a5ab82e605c2ad8e35938bc76&version=stable), then the code works. What makes the specializable implementation different from a regular implementation?

Comment: Because in that case it's a concrete type.

You only need the `default type It = u8;` for it to compile. Since with the Default trait bound, that implementation always works.

See here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0f5da74bbfbbf4f818cefa134d27f4fc&version=nightly

Comment: I don't want to return something simple which can be cretead from Default::default() but I accepted this answer as my example was wrong, and I will use oibits to solve this. I didn't want to use oibits because it seems like forever-unstable, but it works, and I expect specialization feature to be improve support that case